# xcode error on debug build with existing project. (M1 chip)

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-m1

:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NextLevelSessionExporter/NextLevelSessionExporter.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-compressor/react_native_compressor.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-geolocation-service/react_native_geolocation_service.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-pdf-thumbnail/react_native_pdf_thumbnail.modulemap' not found

:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NextLevelSessionExporter/NextLevelSessionExporter.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-compressor/react_native_compressor.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-geolocation-service/react_native_geolocation_service.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-pdf-thumbnail/react_native_pdf_thumbnail.modulemap' not found
Command EmitSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code

:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NextLevelSessionExporter/NextLevelSessionExporter.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-compressor/react_native_compressor.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-geolocation-service/react_native_geolocation_service.modulemap' not found
:0: error: module map file '/Users/victor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fitaye-abbjulghomzhkphclpghuyouibfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-pdf-thumbnail/react_native_pdf_thumbnail.modulemap' not found
Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Add in Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
end
```

and excluded arhitectures add arm64

Comment: After 2 days searching for a solution, this worked for me.

I thought it would be ok because I've seen that it was already configured on XCode "ignored architectures", but this solved anyways. Who knows...

Comment: On the contrary, `Build Active Arch Only` to `Yes` was needed, which is the exact opposite of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing DerivedData. **cmd + k**
And install pods with

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Then build again hopefully it will resolve the issue.

(If the issue still persists. Open properties of terminal check the **rosetta**

Then pod install again using the command i mentioned above.)

Comment: The ruby environment stuff should *never* be run using Rosetta, this is never necessary